# Rails dev on windows with Guard/Livereload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, macos, virtual-machine

I work on a PC for Rails development, because corporate life demands Windows and security.

My current set-up is Ubuntu 14.04 on VM as my dev env, and I test on Windows via the browser. As my code-base expands and my novice abilities grow, I'm looking more into productivity boosters like guard-livereload. Besides this set-up being painfully slow, I want to ask the experts first before I spend hours debugging this awful arrangement.

Is it possible to get guard-livereload and other productivity enhancers to work over a VM guest->windows host connection? Is there a faster/more accepted way to do this?

I cloned my project last night on my personal OSX computer and was reminded why I dev personally on OSX--I'm looking for some productivity boosters for my own morale.

To be clear, I'm not asking "what's best". I'm asking *will guard-livereload and other similar helper gems work across VM* and, is there a *better* windows dev setup than VM guest to windows 7 host.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this but LiveReload uses websockets to notify listeners to reload the page when the file system changes, thus it should not really matter if the browser and server are on different (virtual) machines or even if it is across the network. http://livereload.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my exact work environment and there is no reason why this doesn't work.

Guard/Livereload works fine with a browser connected to the VM, you just have to make sure that you broadcast so that your Windows machine can see it. So when running plain old rails server, that would be:

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

without the `-b 0.0.0.0` your windows machine won't be able to connect. This was a security improvement in a recent version of rails (4.2.0 I think) Likewise you can put this into a Guard file.

```
guard 'rails', server: :thin, host: '0.0.0.0' do     
  watch('Gemfile.lock')     
  watch(%r{^(config|lib)/.*})    
end
```

If you're using an editor on your VM as well as the server running on there make sure you're running on a non-samba share (Guard/watch etc don't place nicely on windows file systems).

In terms of livereload - I've got it working straight out the box and it it uses websockets so providing you have no network restrictions, this should be fine.

An alternative is to use the VM as a pure dev box and ignore windows altogether, just use the browser within your VM to test as you would with your mac.

Comment: Maybe that's my problem? I'm using a samba share b/c my editor is Sublime in windows.

Comment: Just followed your example (with puma)...but chrome livereload can't connect. Do I need to make sure VM ports are open?

Comment: Likely, yes. However you can make it work, try starting guard with force polling option `bundle exec guard -p`. Yes port should be opened.

Comment: You shouldn't need the Chrome extension with the later versions of live reload

Comment: Awesome...I can see that my changes are being recognized by guard. A view change shows `reloading browser` in my terminal...but chrome isn't reloading. I also have to run `guard -p` to get guard to recognize changes. +1 for the help.